# GridBagConstraints.gridheight doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I set the layout of my instance of `JFrame` to `new GridBagLayout()`. I wanted to add a `JTable` to my layout, but the `gridheight` property doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Test");

JTable tblTestTable = new JTable(new Object[][] { {"Bar", "Foo"} }, new Object[] { "Foo", "Bar" });

GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints() {{
    anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    insets = new Insets(2, 5, 2, 5);
    weightx = 1;
    weighty = 1;
}};

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 0;
c.gridheight = 3; // Doesn't work
frame.add(tblTestTable, c);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This is a small piece of my code. The layout manager renders `tblTestTable` as a element with just 1 row, even if I set `gridheight` to `3`. I read something about `gridheight` doesn't working, if `gridx` is bigger than `0`, but I couldn't find a fix for it. Is there already a trick to bypass this?

Comment: That code does not use any `GridLayout` nor the `GridBagConstraints`. Anyway, you are only adding one element to the layout, thus your grid is, in practice, 1x1. What does having gridheight=3 on a 1x1 grid mean? gridheight/width is about how many cells the components take in the grid. This affects the relative position and size of the different components, for a single component it has no meaning.

Comment: No. There are more elements, but I didn't show them here, because the code is a little bit long. It is a 3x3 grid and the table is in (3|0). If I add `c` as second parameter, it still doesn't work correctly and shows as 1x1 table.

Comment: Well, then there's an error in the code we don't see. Make sure that the cells (2, 0) through (2,2) are empty.

Comment: These cells are empty. I have two `JLabel`s in (0, 0) and (0, 1), two `JTextField`s in (1, 0) and (1, 1) and a `JButton` from (0, 2) to (1, 2). (2, 0) to (2, 2) are empty. Should I post the whole code?

Comment: Now it works. Indeed the `JTextField` in (1, 1) was 2 fields in width. Sorry for this bad mistake, but thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure to use the constraints you just built as an argument to the method `add()` in order for the constraints to be applied, like in

```
frame.add(tblTestTable, c);
```

(thx user432)

Comment: Anyway, think about `gridwith` and `gridheight` as colspan and rowspan attributes in an HTML table.  They have only sense when applied to a grid with many elements and show them occupying the rows and columns you tell them

Comment: Of course, this has to be applied to all the elements in the grid (with their own contraints).